# There is no component field [field] in the given Query (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I have a REST GET method that returns list of Services. By providing parameter in query link I would like to be able to sort the list. For example: `sort=price` - sorts list by price in ascending order, if `sort=-price` - sorts in descending order

query looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/services?sort=price
```

Method

```
  public function searchAction(Request $request){
    $sort = $request->query->get('sort');
    $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
    $limit = $request->query->getInt('limit', 5);

    $result = new JsonResponse();

    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Service')->createQueryBuilder('s');

    if($sort != null){

        if($sort == 'price'){
            $qb->addOrderBy('s.price', 'ASC');
        }
        elseif($sort == '-price'){
            $qb->addOrderBy('s.price', 'DESC');
        }
    }

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $serviceListJson = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $page,
        $limit
    );

    $result->setContent($serviceListJson);
    return $result;
   }
```

I get error

```
  There is no component field [price] in the given Query (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Service entity

```
class Service{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer")
 */
private $price;

}
```

I am `using KNP PAginator` bundle

Comment: please add the code for your entity "Service", we can't help you without that.

Comment: @Benoît more than sure that it's not entity problem

Comment: You can search in your Symfony profile where is the source of the exception? Bundle? Vendor?

Comment: The error comes from KNP paginator bundle. You should call it in your template like this: `{{ knp_paginator_sortable(pagination, 'Price', 's.price') }}`

Comment: @malcolm I am using KNP paginator, but not for twig. I am using to sort JSON array in REST API. How can I fix this problem in REST app?

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: @malcolm I updated searchAction code. Without `sort` pagination works perfectly fine.

Comment: Still can't see your query, the `paginateData` method etc. I hope you pass only the query to paginator, not the results.

Comment: @malcolm I updated code, could you check again?

Comment: Can you add before `$paginator` : `$qb = $qb->getQuery();`

Comment: @malcolm still same error

Answer (score 2):

I disabled KNP bundle's `sortable` feature in config.yml to sort in a query

```
 knp_paginator:
    default_options:
       sort_field_name: ~ # Disable sorting
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here for future reference... ;-)

If you would have passed the table-alias along with the field you wish to sort by, it would have worked.

So:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/services?sort=s.price
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/services?sort=price
```